# ionic2 not loading javascript import in UWP app

Tags: javascript, cordova, angular, typescript, ionic2

I have an ionic2 app that works great in the browser however when I try to run it as a UWP app it fails with the following error:

> JavaScript runtime error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in :0:0 caused by: 'Oidc' is undefined

I'm using an oidc library in just one class so I went and looked there and I have the following:

```
import * as Oidc from 'oidc-client';
```

This seems to work fine when running the app in the browser but it doesn't seem to get picked up when run as an app. I don't know if this is a ionic build issue/ webpack / or most likely just my ignorance since i'm relying on a lot of pieces I don't fully understand.

I fixed this issue by directly referencing the script in my index.html file:

```
<script src="oidc-client.min.js"></script>
```

but that really seems like the wrong solution. Can someone point me in the right direction? I want to understand why my import sometimes works.

edit: Also no errors made it back to ionic cli. I had to load this up in Visual Studio to find the problem

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure since I'm not familiar with Oidc, but sometimes doing 'import *' or 'export *' can break things when working with ionic 2 or just straight up angular 2. I think it's more of a webpack related issue. We've had weird build issues or stupid 'X is undefined' issues in our development and oftentimes it's been related to using the wildcards* (I think technically they're called barrels?). Also, some libraries don't play nicely with ES6 modules, although that might not be your case since it runs fine in the browser. Once though I had a really small use case for jquery in an angular 2 app, and the only way to get it in the app was by sticking a link in the index.html. But my gut tells me your problem is with the import statement.